# How can I get the value form associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to get the value form associative array .
Array is

```
$abc=array(10) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "/?p=135" [1]=> string(1) "6" } 
  [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "/?p=81" [1]=> string(1) "6" } 
  [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "/?p=143" [1]=> string(1) "4" } 
  [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "/?p=124" [1]=> string(1) "2" } 
  [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "/?p=21" [1]=> string(1) "2" } 
  [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "/?p=54" [1]=> string(1) "2" } 
  [6]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "/?p=58" [1]=> string(1) "2" } 
  [7]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "/?p=27" [1]=> string(1) "1" } 
  [8]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "/?p=32" [1]=> string(1) "1" } 
  [9]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "/?p=35" [1]=> string(1) "7" } 
}
```

And The value that I want is [1]'s value that [0]'s value is "/?p=35" from $abc.
How can I get ?
Thankyou.

Comment: http://php.net/foreach and some basic string comparison, basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$value = $abc[array_search('/?p=35', array_column($abc, 0))][1];
```

PHP < 5.5.0 use this in place of `array_column`:

```
array_map(function($v) { return $v[0]; }, $abc)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I wrote $value = $abc[array_search('/?p=35', array_map(function($v) { return $v[0]; }, $abc))][1];

Comment: It worked.Thank you for your answer for me such rookie guy.